# check out files in TFS 2010 changeset

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control

We are currently use TFS 2010 source control. I have a change-set that I want to rollback but I want to checkout all the included files and shelf them before checking in the old code. Does anyone know if this is possible? There are many many files and I do not want to go through and check them out by hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the rollback will not actually remove the old files, but will create a new version with the changes removed, you can always see the old version of the files by getting that original changeset number.

No need for shelvesets. Just use get specific version and retrieve the old versions of the file.